# Is it possible to replace / overwrite an existing Modernizr test?

Tags: modernizr, progressive-enhancement

I'm having an issue with a Modernizr test that returns a false positive in one particular browser / OS combination. I've found a replacement test that avoids this issue but which hasn't yet been merged into Modernizr.

I'm thinking the solution would be for me to manually add this replacement test to Modernizr in my site's Javascript until Modernizr gets updated and that false positive is fixed. I'd ideally like it to have the same name as the existing Modernizr test so I don't have to change anything in future when Modernizr gets updated (I'll just remove my custom version of it).

What I'm wondering (but can't find documented) is: is it possible to overwrite an existing Modernizr test, and if so, what's the best way? (As far as I can tell, `Modernizr.addTest('preserve3d' ... )` doesn't overwrite the existing `preserve3d` test - is there a way of doing this?)

Comment: did you report the false result?

Comment: @Patrick The replacement (working) test is actually on a branch of Modernizr that hasn't been merged into their main repo yet.

Comment: im the modernizr maintainer - which feature are you talking about?

Comment: Oh, excellent! It's the branch [`paulirish-patch-1`](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/tree/paulirish-patch-1). The commit that fixes it was from March 10 (it fixes a false positive for preserve3d in IE11 / Windows 10), but it's not merged in yet. For the time being I've got round the above problem by just tracking the branch with the fix, but I'd still be interested to know the answer to this question (ie. is there a way of programatically overwriting / replacing an existing Modernizr test?)